# When to call obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm currently having an issue where creating a new object on a background child thread (whose parent is the main UI thread context) and saving causes my `NSFetchedResultsController` to show two new objects: one with a temporary `objectID`, and one with a permanent `objectID`. This seems to be a bug of some sort, unless I'm missing something.

So I thought I would manually obtain permanent IDs for any new objects I create. This fixes the duplicate row issue, but introduces new random errors (such as "could not fulfill fault for object", refering to the new object I created). If anyone has any ideas as to why any of the previously mentioned is happening, please share.

I'm guessing `obtainPermanentIDs` is a step in the right direction. But when do I call this method? Before saving to the child context? After saving the child and before the parent? After the parent?
Currently my setup is this:

```
masterMOC - private queue tied to the persistent store, so physical saves happen here
----mainMOC - main queue tied to the UI, child of masterMOC
-------backgroundMOC - private queue, child of mainMOC
```

So if I create a new object on `backgroundMOC`, and I intend to immediatly save to disk (which means I'll have to call save: on all three contexts), where should I be calling `obtainPermanentIDs`?

(or if anyone has a different solution other than calling obtain permanent ids? What problem was this method introduced to solve anyway? Why would I want to call this method?)

**Update:**
I think I figured out what's going on (it's only a theory though), though not how to solve it. Core Data apparently generates permanent IDs for objects when they are saved physically to disk. So in my case, this won't happen until I call save on the masterMOC. Currently what I do when creating a new object on the backgroundMOC is:

1. save on backgroundMOC (so that changes are pushed up one level to the mainMOC and the my table view can insert the new rows)
2. save on mainMOC (so that I can prepare for saving to disk)
3. save on masterMOC (which finally saves to disk)

What's happening here is that calling save on the backgroundMOC triggers a UI update, and causes the fetched results controller to insert a new object that still has only a temporary ID. But then calling save on masterMOC causes all objects to get assigned permanent IDs, which causes another UI update, inserting another row for this "new" object! By commenting out the last masterMOC save, I no longer see duplicate entries. Am I doing something wrong here, or is this some kind of bug?

**Another update:** I think I've pretty much confirmed the bug. I call save on the backgroundMOC and then set up a timer to call save on the mainMOC and masterMOC 5 seconds later. Immediatley upon saving to the backgroundMOC, a new row is inserted into my table. 5 seconds later (upon saving main and master), another new row is inserted. (the row inserted first has a temp id, and the newest insert has permanent id).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the exact same issue, of course after a particularly difficult and dispiriting day of debugging everything to find out the issue was temporary IDs. :)

I have the exact same structure as you, and I also have subclasses of NSManagedObjectContext to codify the behavior I expect of saves in the background and main contexts – namely, a save in the background context should save the main context (and the main context should sync any objects that changed with the external service, which is irrelevant but worth mentioning as an explanation for why I have two subclasses), and a save in the main context should save the master context.

In my RFSImportContext subclass (equivalent to your backgroundMOC), I implement `- save:` to call `[super save:]`, then call `[self.parentContext performBlock:]` (self.parentContext here is equivalent to your mainM)C, where the block calls `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:` with the contents of the main context's `- updatedObjects` and `- insertedObjects` arrays, then I save the main context.

I no longer have the leaking of temporary objects into my NSFetchedResultsController as you describe. A way to improve the situation a bit would be to use the RFSMainContext subclass (again, equivalent to your mainMOC) to implement `- save:` to obtain permanent object IDs, save itself, then save the master context. This codifies the behavior that we always want the main context to have permanent IDs for objects in it when it is saved.

Comment: your comment somehow helped me but in another way.
I was using a NSFetchedresultscontroller and it was getting temporaryIds as well as permanent. So everytime the controller calls didchangecontent i make a obtainPermanentIDsForObjects: to all the fetched objects and it works perfectly now!

Comment: @JoãoNunes still not working for me, my ids are already permanent and this error is still prompting

Comment: To clarify, would you call `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:` before or after the `backgroundMOC`'s `save:`? After but before `mainMOC`'s?

Comment: @pr1001 after some parsing it seems to be `bgMoc.save; mainMoc.perform { mainMoc.obtainPermanentIDs; mainMoc.save }` - do you confirm that @refulgentis?